# Any way to erase and use password locked (ATA secure) SSD? (bought used)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, sata, password-protection

So I bought a Kingston HyperX 240gb SATA SSD on Facebook marketplace. When I got home I found out that it's password locked using ATA secure from what I have gathered. The seller promptly blocked me, so I can't return it.

My question is if it is in any way possible to format the drive and unlock it. I don't need to recover any data I would just like to use the drive I paid for.

I did try a couple commands in hdparm which I managed to google, but I have to admit I don't really understand how this stuff works. Anyway I tried, `/dev/sdb` is the locked drive:

```
sudo hdparm --user-master m --security-disable NULL /dev/sdb
```

But I get this error:

```
security_password: ""
 /dev/sdb:Issuing SECURITY_DISABLE command, password="", user=master
 SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:
70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 04 51 e0 00 21 04 00 00 00 01
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

Information from hdparm that could be of use:

```
Security: 
 Master password revision code = 22616
    supported
    enabled
    locked
 not    frozen
 not    expired: security count
    supported: enhanced erase
 Security level high
 4min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 2min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
```

Any help/advice is much appreciated even if you tell me that it is not possible at least I know.

Comment: Make and model of SSD?

Comment: Also I just realized that it might be good to provide the exact model. It is a Kingston HyperX 240gb SATA SSD. S.N./S.N.:SH103S3/240G.

Comment: Hah just realized right before your comment, anyway good point.

Comment: Does the SSD have a label with a "PSID" anywhere on it?

Comment: I am afraid not. Just one label with the P.N, bunch others (I guess batch numbers and such), country of manufacturing (Taiwan), capacity and a lot of logos. I take take a picture, but I am absolutely certain that "PSID" is not on there.

Answer (score 1):

[If I forget the password, can it be reset to use the drive?](https://www.hyperxgaming.com/unitedstates/en/ssd/ssd-faq)

> No. If you forget the password for this drive, it cannot be accessed. Be aware that forgetting your password is not covered under Kingston’s warranty.

> The only exception to this is using a master or administrative password for the drive in addition to the user password. The BIOS would have to support this and it would have to be enabled at the time you initiated the ATA security for this drive. Using a master password would allow an administrator to reset the drive.

Comment: Well that's a bummer. To be honest I did already read this however I kinda hoped that there is a way despite this. Manufactures do tend to claim that things are not possible, or not supported even when they in reality work. And since I did come across some posts where people would suggest that this is possible I had some hope. Anyway it seems I am out of luck and money with an ugly Kingston paperweight. But thanks for taking the time.

Comment: I hope you don't mind if I leave the question up for a day or two, just in case, before I select you answer.

Comment: No problem, there also may be a solution posted later on.